# How do I get more granular with eclipse's Javascript Formatting?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, zend-framework, titanium, code-formatting

I'm using Zend and Titanium and they both lack some simple formatting considerations:

Is there a Crawford formatting plugin somewhere?  Or anything I can fine tune?

from:

```
var foo = "bar", bar = "baz";
```

to:

```
var foo = "bar",
    bar = "baz";
```

and...

from:

```
var str = "this string contains significantly more than eighty characters, how could it be the case that eclipse can't word wrap this? (oh unless it's a comment, which eclipse will happily wrap for you";
```

to:

```
var str = "this string contains significantly more than eighty characters, how"
          + " could it be the case that eclipse can't word wrap this? (oh unless"
          + " it's a comment, which eclipse will happily wrap for you.";
```

I want to wrap anything over 80 characters.  I'm using eclipse only because it makes Titanium Javascript development more easy, and because it's sort-of mandated that I use Zend for PHP/Javascript/HTML/CSS coding.  I see feature requests going back years for this kind of functionality in Eclipse.  It greatly surprises me that this problem isn't solved yet.

Comment: +1 Although, I don't see how to do this easily... Besides writing a custom formatter, which requires some deep eclipse experience. Interested to see if anyone else knows!